# VS2022 Community crashes when adding Class to MFC Dialog

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2022

I am facing a very consistent and persistent problem with Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition.

In an MFC project I open the Resource File and add a new Dialog. Then I place some standard controls and rename the dialog resource from its default name to a new ID.

Then I save and try to assign a Class to the dialog by right-clicking on the dialog and choosing 'Add Class'. Then the 'Add MFC Class' window appears, I enter the Class Name and click [OK].

It appears it creates the class on the File System and then VS2022 crashes completely!

I have disabled all addins in case an addin could be causing the problem but it happens every (almost) every time even without plugins. The only time I manage to get it to work is if I save, close all code editors, exit VS2022, restart it and immediately try to add the class. Another piece of information is that I have changed the MFC dialog template with a different one but it does not seem to bother it when I get it to work. Also intelliSense is completely disabled.

How can I debug this and identify the root cause of this crash?

Answer (score 0):

There's a fair chance that you can't do anything in an effective fashion. VS2022 isn't an open source project, where you can easily pinpoint a crash to a specific line of code and fix it yourself.

But the good thing is that you don't need to. Just use the feedback channel VS2022 provides:

[image: screenshot feedback icon]

Usually a Microsoft employee will reply within a few days and maybe a fix will be included in the next preview version. Only now and then it can take some month to get a bug resolved.